# Arithmetic calculation using previous record for two columns which depends each other in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, recursive-query

In my table I have to calculate values for different columns. The values can be arrived from current row and previous row. These two column values depends on each other.If I change values of one column it affects the other.

I'm sharing a sample table for your reference

```
A   | B   | C   | D
500 | 400 | 400 | 0
300 | 400 | 300 | 100
200 | 500 | 200 | 400
700 | 200 | 600 | 0
900 | 800 | 800 | 0
```

In the above table I have to calculate C and D column. Excel formula is:

- 1st row of C is IF(A2>B2,B2,A2)
- 2nd row to Final row of C is IF(A3>B3+D2,B3+D2,A3)
- 1st row of D is IF(A2-B2<=0,-1*(A2-B2),0)
- 2nd row to Final row of D is IF(A3-(B3+D2)<=0,-1*(A3-(B3+D2)),0)

How to arrive the same in sql

```
CREATE TABLE sampl (A int, B int);
INSERT INTO SAMPL VALUES (500, 400);
INSERT INTO SAMPL VALUES (300, 400);
INSERT INTO SAMPL VALUES (200, 500);
INSERT INTO SAMPL VALUES (700, 200);
INSERT INTO SAMPL VALUES (900, 800);
SELECT * FROM sampl
SELECT *, CASE WHEN A>B THEN B ELSE A END C, CASE WHEN A-B<=0 THEN -1*(A-B) ELSE 0 END D FROM sampl
```

How to arrive for multiple records

```
rn  Tab a   b   c   d    
1   AA  500 400 400 0    
2   AA  300 400 300 100    
3   AA  200 500 200 400    
4   AA  700 200 600 0    
5   AA  900 800 800 0    
1   BB  500 400 400 0    
2   BB  300 400 300 100    
3   BB  200 500 200 400   
4   BB  700 200 600 0
```

Comment: SQL isn't Excel; don't treat it like it. You can't reference other rows by a column and row index value.

Comment: You need to look at [the lag function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Do you have any kind of column that we can use the determine the order of these rows; neither `A` nor `B` are in ascending order. There is no "Order of insertion" in SQL Server, data is stored in an **unordered** heap. If you need to be able to reference the next/previous row you can do so by using `LEAD`/`LAG`, however, you have to have an `ORDER BY` clause to do so. `ORDER BY sampl.A` would not retain the order of the rows as you inserted them.

Comment: This can only be done with recursion because d depends on... d.

Comment: Looks like an rCTE would be one method then. Still, we need a way to determine the order of the data with an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: You have the value `0` for `D` in the first row, but I get `100`. `IF(A2-B2<=0,-1*(A2-B2),0)  = IF(300-400<=0,-1*(300-400),0) = IF(-100<=0,100,0) = 100`. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have translated the formula to a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (tab VARCHAR(100), rn INT, a INT, b INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('aa', 1, 500, 400),
('aa', 2, 300, 400),
('aa', 3, 200, 500),
('aa', 4, 700, 200),
('aa', 5, 900, 800),
('bb', 1, 500, 400),
('bb', 2, 300, 400),
('bb', 3, 200, 500),
('bb', 4, 700, 200);

WITH rcte AS (
    SELECT tab
         , rn
         , a
         , b
         , IIF(a > b, b, a) AS c
         , IIF(a - b <= 0, -1 * (a - b), 0) AS d
    FROM @tbl
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT curr.tab
         , curr.rn
         , curr.a
         , curr.b
         , IIF(curr.a > curr.b + prev.d, curr.b + prev.d, curr.a)
         , IIF(curr.a - (curr.b + prev.d) <= 0, -1 * (curr.a - (curr.b + prev.d)), 0)
    FROM @tbl AS curr
    JOIN rcte AS prev ON curr.tab = prev.tab AND curr.rn = prev.rn + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM rcte
ORDER BY tab, rn
```

Note that I added the `rn` column to the data. You could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tab ORDER BY foo)` to generate this column if necessary. Also note that `a - b <= 0` could be written as `a <= b`.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8352dd3b058541878233e117e168575)

Comment: Its working. How to arrive the same for multiple records

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . I'm pretty sure a recursive CTE is needed for this because of the `if()`.